# Фильтр по цене для нескольких валют

Tags: битрикс

Есть товары простые и с товарными предложениями, все в разных валютах.
"Умный фильтр" показывает диапазон цен только в одной валюте, других цен не замечает.

Есть ли какое-то решение по корректной работе? Использование `MIN_PRICE` не подходит, так как оно есть только для товарных предложений, в обычных товарах отсутствует.

Bitrix 15, "Малый бизнес".

Comment: А что мешает хранить в одной валюте? Есть ведь модуль валют: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/settings/currency/index.php

Comment: @ka3a, в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/catalog/smart_filter.php) есть пример вызова умного фильтра с параметрами CONVERT_CURRENCY и CURRENCY_ID. Не работает. Судя по запросам пользователей, проблема актуальна как минимум с 2013 года.

Comment: Раз не работает, то я бы на вашем месте написал в тех поддержку. Там больше вероятности, что вам помогут :)

Comment: На мой взгляд, это прямая дорога в ад: когда число ваших товаров вырастет до десятка тысяч, умный фильтр просто перестанет ворочаться.

Answer (score 2):

Для торговых предложений не пробовал, но для обычных товаров в шаблоне комплексного компонента `bitrix:catalog`, перед вызовом компонента `bitrix:catalog.section`, использую такой код:

```
if (CModule::IncludeModule('currency')
    && !empty($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]])
    && (
        !empty($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['>=CATALOG_PRICE_1'])
        || !empty($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['>=CATALOG_PRICE_1'])
        || !empty($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['><CATALOG_PRICE_1'])
    )
) {
    if (!empty($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['><CATALOG_PRICE_1'])) {
        $GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['>=CATALOG_PRICE_1'] = $GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['><CATALOG_PRICE_1'][0];
        $GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['<=CATALOG_PRICE_1'] = $GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['><CATALOG_PRICE_1'][1];
        unset($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['><CATALOG_PRICE_1']);
    }
    $arCurrency = array();
    $res = CCurrency::GetList($by = 'currency', $order = 'asc');
    while ($arRes = $res->Fetch()) {
        $arCurrency[] = $arRes['CURRENCY'];
    }

    if (!empty($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['>=CATALOG_PRICE_1']) && count($arCurrency) > 1) {
        $arPriceFilter = array('LOGIC' => 'OR');
        foreach ($arCurrency as $currency) {
            $price = floatval($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['>=CATALOG_PRICE_1']);
            if ($arParams['CURRENCY_ID'] != $currency) {
                $price = CCurrencyRates::ConvertCurrency($price, $arParams['CURRENCY_ID'], $currency);
            }
            $arPriceFilter[] = array(
                'CATALOG_CURRENCY_1' => $currency,
                '>=CATALOG_PRICE_1' => $price,
            );
        }
        $GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]][] = $arPriceFilter;
        unset($arPriceFilter);
        unset($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['>=CATALOG_PRICE_1']);
    }

    if (!empty($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['<=CATALOG_PRICE_1']) && count($arCurrency) > 1) {
        $arPriceFilter = array('LOGIC' => 'OR');
        foreach ($arCurrency as $currency) {
            $price = floatval($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['<=CATALOG_PRICE_1']);
            if ($arParams['CURRENCY_ID'] != $currency) {
                $price = CCurrencyRates::ConvertCurrency($price, $arParams['CURRENCY_ID'], $currency);
            }
            $arPriceFilter[] = array(
                'CATALOG_CURRENCY_1' => $currency,
                '<=CATALOG_PRICE_1' => $price,
            );
        }
        $GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]][] = $arPriceFilter;
        unset($arPriceFilter);
        unset($GLOBALS[$arParams["FILTER_NAME"]]['<=CATALOG_PRICE_1']);
    }
}
```

Естественно, все отрабатывает корректно только для типа цены с `ID = 1`, кому требуется другой - меняйте `CATALOG_PRICE_1` и `CATALOG_CURRENCY_1` на нужные.